# Puting javascript execution script in remote file

Tags: jquery, execution

I found a question similar to my question but the answer didn't work for me.  I have a navigation that I found online that works with JQuery.

I put the navigation execution script in an external file and linked it, but now it doesn't work.  Can someone explain why it wont work?  I also tried the $(document).ready(function that didnt work either.

I put the reference to the file in the head

I've updated my Javascript, this doesn't work either

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(function() {
            $('#hn_menu > li').bind('mouseenter',function(){
        var $elem = $(this);
            $elem.find('img')
       .stop(true)
       .animate({
       //'width':'170px',
       'width':'120px',
       //'height':'170px',
       'height':'120px',
       'left':'0px'
    },400,'easeOutBack')
    .andSelf()
    .find('.hn_wrap')
    blah blah blah
        });
    });
```

here's the entire document.. I need to convert this mess to an external file script

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Slide Down Box Menu with jQuery and CSS3</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="description" content="Slide Down Box Menu with jQuery and CSS3" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="jquery, css3, sliding, box, menu, cube, navigation, portfolio, thumbnails"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
    <style>
        body{
            background:#333 url(bg.jpg) repeat top left;
            font-family:Arial;
        }
        span.reference{
            position:fixed;
            left:10px;
            bottom:10px;
            font-size:12px;
        }
        span.reference a{
            color:#aaa;
            text-transform:uppercase;
            text-decoration:none;
            text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;
            margin-right:30px;
        }
        span.reference a:hover{
            color:#ddd;
        }
        ul.sdt_menu{
            margin-top:150px;
        }
        h1.title{
            text-indent:-9000px;
            background:transparent url(title.png) no-repeat top left;
            width:633px;
            height:69px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="testexec.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="content">
        <h1 class="title">Slide Down Box Menu with jQuery and CSS3</h1>
        <ul id="sdt_menu" class="sdt_menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="images/2.jpg" alt=""/>
                    <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                    <span class="sdt_wrap">
                        <span class="sdt_link">About me</span>
                        <span class="sdt_descr">Get to know me</span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="images/1.jpg" alt=""/>
                    <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                    <span class="sdt_wrap">
                        <span class="sdt_link">Portfolio</span>
                        <span class="sdt_descr">My work</span>
                    </span>
                </a>
                <div class="sdt_box">
                        <a href="#">Websites</a>
                        <a href="#">Illustrations</a>
                        <a href="#">Photography</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="images/3.jpg" alt=""/>
                    <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                    <span class="sdt_wrap">
                        <span class="sdt_link">Inspiration</span>
                        <span class="sdt_descr">Where ideas get born</span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="images/4.jpg" alt=""/>
                    <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                    <span class="sdt_wrap">
                        <span class="sdt_link">Photos</span>
                        <span class="sdt_descr">I like to photograph</span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="images/5.jpg" alt=""/>
                    <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                    <span class="sdt_wrap">
                        <span class="sdt_link">Blog</span>
                        <span class="sdt_descr">I write about design</span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="images/6.jpg" alt=""/>
                    <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                    <span class="sdt_wrap">
                        <span class="sdt_link">Projects</span>
                        <span class="sdt_descr">I like to code</span>
                    </span>
                </a>
                <div class="sdt_box">
                    <a href="#">Job Board Website</a>
                    <a href="#">Shopping Cart</a>
                    <a href="#">Interactive Maps</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="reference">
```

More script and css style
: [www.htmldrive.net](http://www.htmldrive.net/)

```
    <!-- The JavaScript -->
   <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            /**
            * for each menu element, on mouseenter, 
            * we enlarge the image, and show both sdt_active span and 
            * sdt_wrap span. If the element has a sub menu (sdt_box),
            * then we slide it - if the element is the last one in the menu
            * we slide it to the left, otherwise to the right
            */
            $('#sdt_menu > li').bind('mouseenter',function(){
                var $elem = $(this);
                $elem.find('img')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({
                        'width':'170px',
                        'height':'170px',
                        'left':'0px'
                     },400,'easeOutBack')
                     .andSelf()
                     .find('.sdt_wrap')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({'top':'140px'},500,'easeOutBack')
                     .andSelf()
                     .find('.sdt_active')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({'height':'170px'},300,function(){
                    var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
                    if($sub_menu.length){
                        var left = '170px';
                        if($elem.parent().children().length == $elem.index()+1)
                            left = '-170px';
                        $sub_menu.show().animate({'left':left},200);
                    }   
                });
            }).bind('mouseleave',function(){
                var $elem = $(this);
                var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
                if($sub_menu.length)
                    $sub_menu.hide().css('left','0px');

                $elem.find('.sdt_active')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({'height':'0px'},300)
                     .andSelf().find('img')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({
                        'width':'0px',
                        'height':'0px',
                        'left':'85px'},400)
                     .andSelf()
                     .find('.sdt_wrap')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({'top':'25px'},500);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: should work fine assuming path to file is correct and file is included after jquery.js. Any errors thrown in browser console? Using console can also validate path is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple things that could be the problem.  Here is a basic guideline to follow:

write the `<script>` link in the `<head>` tag like this:

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/your-root-folder/your-script.js"></script>
</head>
```

Then, in `your-script.js`, you need to wrap the function in $(document).ready(function(){...}

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //call the function here
});
```

**EDIT**

Your problem is the order in which you have linked your script files.  the jQuery link and Easing link need to come before your script.  Notice in the example I gave `your-script.js` is after `jquery.min.js`.

**Copy and replace everything:**

The html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Slide Down Box Menu with jQuery and CSS3</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="description" content="Slide Down Box Menu with jQuery and CSS3" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="jquery, css3, sliding, box, menu, cube, navigation, portfolio, thumbnails"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
    <style>
        body{
            background:#333 url(bg.jpg) repeat top left;
            font-family:Arial;
        }
        span.reference{
            position:fixed;
            left:10px;
            bottom:10px;
            font-size:12px;
        }
        span.reference a{
            color:#aaa;
            text-transform:uppercase;
            text-decoration:none;
            text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;
            margin-right:30px;
        }
        span.reference a:hover{
            color:#ddd;
        }
        ul.sdt_menu{
            margin-top:150px;
        }
        h1.title{
            text-indent:-9000px;
            background:transparent url(title.png) no-repeat top left;
            width:633px;
            height:69px;
        }
    </style>
    <!-- The JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="content">
        <h1 class="title">Slide Down Box Menu with jQuery and CSS3</h1>
        <ul id="sdt_menu" class="sdt_menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="images/2.jpg" alt=""/>
                    <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                    <span class="sdt_wrap">
                        <span class="sdt_link">About me</span>
                        <span class="sdt_descr">Get to know me</span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="images/1.jpg" alt=""/>
                    <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                    <span class="sdt_wrap">
                        <span class="sdt_link">Portfolio</span>
                        <span class="sdt_descr">My work</span>
                    </span>
                </a>
                <div class="sdt_box">
                        <a href="#">Websites</a>
                        <a href="#">Illustrations</a>
                        <a href="#">Photography</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="images/3.jpg" alt=""/>
                    <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                    <span class="sdt_wrap">
                        <span class="sdt_link">Inspiration</span>
                        <span class="sdt_descr">Where ideas get born</span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="images/4.jpg" alt=""/>
                    <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                    <span class="sdt_wrap">
                        <span class="sdt_link">Photos</span>
                        <span class="sdt_descr">I like to photograph</span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="images/5.jpg" alt=""/>
                    <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                    <span class="sdt_wrap">
                        <span class="sdt_link">Blog</span>
                        <span class="sdt_descr">I write about design</span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="images/6.jpg" alt=""/>
                    <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                    <span class="sdt_wrap">
                        <span class="sdt_link">Projects</span>
                        <span class="sdt_descr">I like to code</span>
                    </span>
                </a>
                <div class="sdt_box">
                    <a href="#">Job Board Website</a>
                    <a href="#">Shopping Cart</a>
                    <a href="#">Interactive Maps</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
            <span class="reference">More script and css style: <a href="http://www.htmldrive.net/" title="HTML DRIVE - Free DHMTL Scripts,Jquery plugins,Javascript,CSS,CSS3,Html5 Library">www.htmldrive.net</a>               
            </span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The external javascript which I named `test.js`:

```
// JavaScript Document
$(function() {
            /**
            * for each menu element, on mouseenter, 
            * we enlarge the image, and show both sdt_active span and 
            * sdt_wrap span. If the element has a sub menu (sdt_box),
            * then we slide it - if the element is the last one in the menu
            * we slide it to the left, otherwise to the right
            */
            $('#sdt_menu > li').bind('mouseenter',function(){
                var $elem = $(this);
                $elem.find('img')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({
                        'width':'170px',
                        'height':'170px',
                        'left':'0px'
                     },400,'easeOutBack')
                     .andSelf()
                     .find('.sdt_wrap')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({'top':'140px'},500,'easeOutBack')
                     .andSelf()
                     .find('.sdt_active')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({'height':'170px'},300,function(){
                    var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
                    if($sub_menu.length){
                        var left = '170px';
                        if($elem.parent().children().length == $elem.index()+1)
                            left = '-170px';
                        $sub_menu.show().animate({'left':left},200);
                    }   
                });
            }).bind('mouseleave',function(){
                var $elem = $(this);
                var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
                if($sub_menu.length)
                    $sub_menu.hide().css('left','0px');

                $elem.find('.sdt_active')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({'height':'0px'},300)
                     .andSelf().find('img')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({
                        'width':'0px',
                        'height':'0px',
                        'left':'85px'},400)
                     .andSelf()
                     .find('.sdt_wrap')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({'top':'25px'},500);
            });
        });
```

Comment: I am not sure what I am missing, I used the source file that I got it from and made these changes and it doesn't work. I added the $(document).ready(function() { the pasted in the execution above that was in the body, also in the body above it was the script source.. I put that in the head also. I am pretty sure I got everything but there is still something amiss I'll post the source code of the menu

Comment: @JakeZeitz `$(function() {})` is shorthand for `$(document).ready(function() {})`

Comment: @ColinDeClue How bout that, I just assumed it was an anonymous function. Well that would explain why wrapping it in document.ready did not work for him.

Comment: @JeremyWinslow can you show what your `<script>` link looks like?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="testexec.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>

Comment: Thats in the head, it was in the body with the execution script

Comment: I fixed the order, still broken.. I am going to see if I can get you the link where I downloaded it from..

Comment: make sure testexec.js only includes the javscript code and no html. Also, make sure to remove the function from the html as it is now in a separate file

Comment: Yes I commented out all javascript and references in the body and added it to the head section, added the execution script to the external file and referenced that in the head, rearranged the order of the files also. Still no bueno, I gave you the link of the download where I got it, that might help clear it up.  Thanks a million for helping me on this.  This is something I been trying to do for ages.

Comment: I really can't tell why it won't work, everything says it should work.

Comment: I got it to work in downloading that file. Im gonna post the whole thing and your gonna copy all of it.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work without having any scripts in the body?

Comment: Yup, you can simply cut and past the `<script>` tags from the bottom of the `<body>` tag and place them in the `<head>` tag. I'll update my answer to show it correctly.